# Accessing 3rd party API from wix

Tags: javascript, velo

I am trying to communicate with a 3rd party API.  I wrote the API in python. I want to update the name column in the database from the Wix web page using a user form and text box. The database updates and all of the endpoints are responsive using postman to test.  I think the problem resides in my JavaScript on the Wix end.

I modeled the JavaScript from the Wix example at:
https://support.wix.com/en/article/calling-server-side-code-from-the-front-end-with-web-modules

I have a back end module called placeOrder stored in orderplaced.jsw that should post the variable 'name' to the api.

```
import { fetch } from 'wix-fetch';
// wix-fetch is the API we provide to make https calls in the backend

export function placeOrder(name) {
 return fetch("https://reliableeparts.pythonanywhere.com/user", {
        method: 'post',
        name: JSON.stringify({ name })

    }).then(function (response) {
 if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300){
            console.log(JSON.stringify({ name }))
 return response.text();}

    console.log(Error(response.statusText))



 return Error(response.statusText);}

    );
}
```

The front end module waits for a button click and stores the text box in the name variable.

```
{
import {placeOrder} from 'backend/orderplaced.jsw';

export function button1_click(event, $w) {
     placeOrder(
         $w("#input1").value)

         .then(function() {
            console.log("Form submitted to backend.");
        }
     );
}
}
```

Output:
[image: output][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qbk5s.jpg)
The code appears to be reaching the back end.  I believe the problem is in my placeOrder function as I am not very familiar with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems legit. The problem is with the server. When I tried to send a `POST` request to that address I got a `500 Internal Server Error`.

You may check this `curl` and test the service yourself:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" https://reliableeparts.pythonanywhere.com/user -d '{"name":"test123"}'
```

You are probably missing the correct object structure the server is expecting or missing proper headers to `POST` the server (or both...)

Make sure you're following the API this server allows